# Opera pass click to overlaped button

Tags: javascript, button, opera

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 25px; position: relative;">
    <input type="button" style="width: 100px; height: 25px;" onclick="alert(1);" value="Input"/>
    <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.3;"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 25px; position: relative;">
    <button style="width: 100px; height: 25px;" onclick="alert(1);">Button</button>
    <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.3;"></div>
</div>
```

When I click on first button(<input>) in Opera 11.01, button don't pressed, because next <div> overlaps <input>. But if I click on second button(<button>), it is visually pressed(event OnClick isn't called). Such behavior is observed in Opera only, in Firefox and Chrome behavior is normal - buttons aren't pressed. What's wrong?

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkQRW/23/)

Updated:
Behavior:

- Click to first button in Chrome. It's not clickable, alert doesn't appear. **Correct**;
- Click to second button in Chrome. It's not clickable, alert doesn't appear. **Correct**;
- Click to first button in Opera. It's not clickable, alert doesn't appear. **Correct**;
- Click to second button in Opera. Button visually clicked(!!) - button's style changed to state "pressed", alert doesn't appear. **Incorrect** - Button shouldn't be pressed, because it is blocked by div. Behavior should coincide with first button;

Comment: On Chrome 12 Dev, I'm not getting any `alert()` messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a z-index on the div

```
<div style="width: 100px; height: 25px; position: relative;">
    <button style="width: 100px; height: 25px;" onclick="alert(1);">Inpute</button>
    <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.3; z-indeX: -1;"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 25px; position: relative;">
    <button style="width: 100px; height: 25px;" onclick="alert(1);">Button</button>
    <div style="top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.3; z-index: -1;"></div>
</div>
```

Updated: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLfjk/3/)

Comment: No, problem not that I can't press button. There is div which overlap the button. It must be over of button that I couldn't press button. My solution works in Firefox and Chrome, but doesn't work in Opera. In Opera second button is pressed despite the fact that it overlaps div - this in problem. I do not want to second button is pressed in Opera

Comment: Your solution doesn't work in IE9 either, if you are simply wishing to disable the button why not just add the attribute 'disabled' to the button?

Comment: Solution should work in firefox, chrome and opera. IE is ignored. Attribute "disabled" doesn't approach for solution of this task. I can solve problem if I will use <input type="button"> instead of <button>. But I want to understand - in what a problem with <button> in opera